# Types of blockchains

Tags: digital-signature, blockchain, membership, consensus

I'm trying to find and compare different types of blockchains regarding communication, consensus, membership management and validation of signatures. I want to find different blockchains for the following characteristics:

- Communication (Pure P2P, Hybrid, C/S)
- Consensus (PoW, PBFT, PoS, PoET, etc..)
- Membership management (Public / Private / Consortium)
- Validation of signatures (Traditional signatures, Multisignature, Threshold signatures)

The easiest characteristic to find and compare is consensus and membership management, although I'm currently finding difficult to see each blockchain in terms of Communication and Validation of Signatures, can someone help me? The main blockchains I'm focusing are Bitcoin, Ethereum (and Quorum), Hyperledger Fabric, Namecoin, and others if possible. What blockchains are not pure P2P?

I'm aware this is not an exact question but I'm looking for someone that might be able to help me on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Many or most blockchains use ECDSA with curve secp256k1 for signing. Bitcoin and Ethereum uses this, as does Hyperledger Sawtooth.

Hyperledger Sawtooth uses ZeroMQ (ZMQ or 0MQ) to communicate between blockchain nodes. ZMQ uses ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 for key agreement. This is just for "data in flight", it is not used with "data at rest" in the global state or in the blockchain.